# Power BI Previous element by date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

The target result:

[image]

I use the formula for new column:

```
previousTaskName = var previous = CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK (Process[PYTASKNAME];"");
    FILTER ( 
      Process;
      Process[PXHISTORYFORREFERENCE] = EARLIER(Process[PXHISTORYFORREFERENCE])
        && Process[PXTIMECREATED] > EARLIER(Process[PXTIMECREATED])
    )
)
return
IF (ISBLANK(previous); BLANK(); previous)
```

The actual result:

[image]

Could anybody tell me where I take a mistake?

Comment: Are the table records in order by time created ?

Comment: Yes. I have column 'PXTIMEFLOWSTARTED' where values like '20180914T131330.792 GMT'. I sort by this column because it have milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The EARLIER function in that context refers to the value from the current row, so you probably need to change your > to <.

Also the FIRSTNONBLANK function will give you the first value using the fields sort sequence - probably alphabetic in your scenario.  So with a more complex test case, any prior row with Agreement will result in Agreement - this might not be what you wanted.

You probably want to create another intermediate VAR to catch the MAX ( Process[PXTIMECREATED] ) from the set of prior rows, then write another CALCULATE ... FILTER to return the PYTASKNAME from the most recent prior row.

You will also have cleaner code if you replace your EARLIER functions with more VAR definitions, e.g.

```
VAR vPXHISTORYFORREFERENCE = [PXHISTORYFORREFERENCE]
```